# transform a dataframe into an array with 3d shape (x,y,z)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, artificial-intelligence

I have a DF as below and I want to change it format so that i get an array with the following shape (3,Y,2) where 3 indicated that there are 3 labels (a b and c) and U is the number of rows for each label (as they vary between each other I didn't specify it and it is not that import to me) and 2 indicates that there is 2 features/columns (data_1 and data_2) `[[[1.09,1][5.0,3],[2.1,2][2.0,3],[1.9,4]]]`. as far I as understand it will be 3d array. I want to feed the output to an lstm model

```
label  data_1 data_2
a      1.09   1
b      2.1    2
a      5.0    3
b      2.0    3
c      1.9    4
```

Answer (score -1):

Given `label` as your index already if you sort it..

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
```

Then...

```
df.to_numpy()
array([[1.09, 1.  ],
       [5.  , 3.  ],
       [2.1 , 2.  ],
       [2.  , 3.  ],
       [1.9 , 4.  ]])
```

---

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'c'},
 'data_1': {0: 1.09, 1: 2.1, 2: 5.0, 3: 2.0, 4: 1.9},
 'data_2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 4}})

df = df.set_index('label')

    data_1  data_2
label       
a   1.09    1
b   2.10    2
a   5.00    3
b   2.00    3
c   1.90    4

df = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
print(df.to_numpy())

[[1.09 1.  ]
 [5.   3.  ]
 [2.1  2.  ]
 [2.   3.  ]
 [1.9  4.  ]]
```